# Django Formset.is_valid missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms, formset

I was debugging my program and I noticed that on the line `Formset.is_valid`  i am getting error:

```
missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Could you please advise how it could be solved to make `formset` and all the forms to validate successfully and save to database. Also, is double validation (`formset` and `form`) necessary? Thank you for insights.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import modelformset_factory, AssumptionsForm
from .models import Assumptions
import pdb

model_names = ['Form1', 'Form2']


def get_assumptions(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        print('Reached post')

        formset = modelformset_factory(
            Assumptions, form=AssumptionsForm, extra=5)

        pdb.set_trace()

        for thing in model_names:

            if thing in request.POST:

                print('template name in model_names')

                if formset.is_valid():

                    for form in formset:

                        if form.is_valid():

                        print('in for loop after valid form1')

                        assumptions = form.save(commit='False')
                        assumptions.Name = thing
                        assumptions.save()

    else:

        formset = modelformset_factory(
            Assumptions, form=AssumptionsForm, extra=5)

        print('reached else')

    return render(request, 'assumptions.html', {'formset': formset, 'model_names': model_names})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Assumptions(models.Model):

    Worst_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Grey_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Red_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Blue_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Green_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Best_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

**assumptions.html**

```
<div class="form">
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{{ formset.non_form_errors.as_ul }}
{% for vardas in model_names %}
<h1>{{vardas}}</h1>
<table id="formset" class="form">
{% for form in formset.forms %}
  {% if forloop.first %}
  <thead><tr>
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr></thead>
  {% endif %}
  <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
  {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <td>
    {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
    {% if forloop.first %}
      {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
      {{ hidden }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
      {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
      {{ field }}
    </td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="{{vardas}}" />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Next">

</form>
</div>
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import modelformset_factory, ModelForm
from .models import Assumptions

class AssumptionsForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Assumptions
        fields = ['Worst_Case', 'Grey_Case', 'Red_Case', 'Blue_Case', 'Green_Case', 'Best_Case']
        exclude = ['Name']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't instantiated your formset. A factory is something that returns a class, so here `modelformset_factory` returns a formset class that you then need to instantiate in both your get and post blocks.

```
def get_assumptions(request):

    AssumptionsFormset = modelformset_factory(
        Assumptions, form=AssumptionsForm, extra=5)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AssumptionsFormset(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            ...
    else:
        formset = AssumptionsFormset()
    return render(request, 'assumptions.html', {'formset': formset, 'model_names': model_names})
```

Also note, you don't need to check `is_valid()` on each form; if the formset is valid, all the forms will be valid.

Comment: Thank you! It saves to database now, but only the Form2 data, would you be so kind to advise how to save both Form1 and Form2 data without overwriting?

Comment: Anyway, I accept this great answer and create new question for overwritten data in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218297/django-for-loop-overwrites-saved-modelform