# Django for loop overwrites saved modelform

Tags: django, loops, modelform, formset

The following code saves to database but the values inputted to the form2 overwrites values inputted to Form1 in database. However the Assumptions.Name is not overwritten and has both values Form1 and Form2. Also, if I refresh the page form is expanding and have more rows with previously saved values in it. How to avoid and save Form1 and Form2 data to database correctly?

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import modelformset_factory, AssumptionsForm
from .models import Assumptions
import pdb

model_names = ['Form1', 'Form2']


def get_assumptions(request):

    AssumptionsFormset = modelformset_factory(
    Assumptions, form=AssumptionsForm, extra=5)

    if request.method == 'POST':

        print('Reached post')

        pdb.set_trace()

        for thing in model_names:

            formset = AssumptionsFormset(request.POST)

            if formset.is_valid():



                if thing in request.POST:

                    print('template name in model_names')

                    for form in formset:

                        print('in for loop' +thing)

                        assumptions = form.save(commit='False')
                        assumptions.Name = thing
                        assumptions.save()

    else:

        formset = AssumptionsFormset()

        print('reached else')

    return render(request, 'assumptions.html', {'formset': formset, 'model_names': model_names})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Assumptions(models.Model):

    Worst_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Grey_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Red_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Blue_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Green_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Best_Case = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    Name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

**assumptions.html**

```
<div class="form">
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{{ formset.non_form_errors.as_ul }}
{% for vardas in model_names %}
<h1>{{vardas}}</h1>
<table id="formset" class="form">
{% for form in formset.forms %}
  {% if forloop.first %}
  <thead><tr>
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr></thead>
  {% endif %}
  <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
  {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <td>
    {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
    {% if forloop.first %}
      {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
      {{ hidden }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
      {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
      {{ field }}
    </td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="{{vardas}}" />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Next">

</form>
</div>
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import modelformset_factory, ModelForm
from .models import Assumptions

class AssumptionsForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Assumptions
        fields = ['Worst_Case', 'Grey_Case', 'Red_Case', 'Blue_Case', 'Green_Case', 'Best_Case']
        exclude = ['Name']
```